# How to set a Bit in an Integer without using a bitmask

Tags: c++

I want to set a bit on an integer but without creating a bitmask to help me.

Example: a=128 and masc=00000001 ...a&masc=10000001

Example on how to do it with a bitmask:

```
int y,masc;
int a=128;
masc=0x01;
y=a|masc;
cout<<y;
```

The question now is: **Is there a way to do this without the bitmask and if possible shorter then this code?**

Comment: Please show some real code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I hammered this into shape a little.

Comment: What's wrong with `y = a|mask` ? That's already very short.

Comment: @MichaelWalz he wants to do it without the bitmask, presumably due to a homework question that says this.

Comment: Why do you need to set a bit without the `|` operator?

Comment: Just asking if there is short way to improve that

Comment: How would any mechanism that does not involve a bitmask and boolean algebra be of any use to future SO users/visitors?

Comment: `++a`  ..............

Comment: How exactly do you expect a method to be shorter than `|` ??

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways of doing this but it's tricky to offer a 'better' solution without knowing why simply using a bit mask is a problem. For example, you could use a helper function along the lines of:

```
template< typename BITS> inline BITS set_bit(BITS data, size_t pos, bool val)
{
    return ( val ) ? data | ( 1 << pos ) : data & ~ ( 1 << pos );
}

unsigned int a = 128;
a = set_bit(a, 0, true);
std::cout << a << std::endl;   // gives 129 = 10000001
a = set_bit(a, 4, true);
std::cout << a << std::endl;   // gives 145 = 10010001
a = set_bit(a, 7, false);
std::cout << a << std::endl;   // gives 17  = 00010001
```

(Note that I've not added any bounds checking to this on the `pos` parameter)

Another way to do this might be to use a *bitfield* which allows you to declare variable names for individual bit and groups of bits of a larger type as follows:

```
struct MyBits {
    unsigned int alpha : 1,
                 beta : 1,
                 gamma : 1;
};

MyBits b;
b.alpha = 1;
b.gamma = 1;

std::cout << b.alpha << std::endl;  // gives 1
std::cout << b.beta << std::endl;   // gives 0
std::cout << b.gamma << std::endl;  // gives 1
```

A third way - although this is not strictly using an `int` as such - might be to use a *bitset* to achieve a similar job:

```
#include <bitset>

std::bitset<8> c;
c[0] = true;
c[2] = true;

std::cout << c[0] << std::endl; // gives 1
std::cout << c[1] << std::endl; // gives 0
std::cout << c[2] << std::endl; // gives 1
```

All have their advantages and disadvantages. It largely depends on the motivating factors behind your question.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ (and computers in general) you have two types of operations: numerical and bit operations. Since you want to avoid the latter, you have to use the former.

Luckily there's a simple association between bits and numbers. Bits in an integer correspond to powers of two. The lowest bit represents 2^0=1, the next one 2^1=2 etcetera.

We need to start with the highest power of two:

```
int p2 = (INT_MAX - INT_MAX/2);
```

and then copy every set bit over:

```
int result = 0
while (p2 > 0)
{
    if (a>p2) // This bit is set in a2, copy it.
    {
         result += p2;
         a -= p2;
    }
    p2 /= 2;
}
```

except when p2 is the bit you want to set, of course. I'll leave that part of the exercise to you.

Answer (score -1):

You can try a macro like this

```
#define SET_BIT(data, bit) (data) |= 1 << (bit);
```

Usage

```
int num = 0;
SET_BIT(num, 2);    // num = 4
```